# Unlocking files and folders locked by some employee who is no longer in the company

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Like the title says, I'm facing a huge problem with some projects in our TFS. We can't do any check-in with changes because some old employee checked-out (and not checked-in) or simply they've locked those files.

With some research, I've tried to go for some **Command Lines** but no success.

I've checked my permissions to do changes in TFS like [Microsoft's guide said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/lock-unlock-folders-files?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) and tried some commands:

Tried to unlock:

```
tf lock $"/Project_directory/branch/etc" /lock:none /workspace:"WORKSPACE;NAME_EMPLOYEE" /recursive /collection:"http://TFSNAME:8080/tfs"
```

Tried to delete the workspace:

```
tf workspaces /remove:"WORKSPACE_NAME" /server:https://TFSNAME
```

Tried to undo the check-out:

```
tf undo $"/Project_directory/branch/etc" /workspace:"WORKSPACE;NAME_EMPLOYEE" /server:https://TFSNAME
```

Asking some colleagues, they said in olders versions of Visual Studio and TFS you only needed to click and unlock in Source Control Explorer but the option is always disabled.

Example:
Right click in file or folder > Advanced > Unlock option disabled

Comment: do you have the permissions to run those commands?

Comment: I disagree with the current "off topic > Server Fault" vote. This is about TFVC, a version control system that is _primarly_ for programming. This is just as much on-topic as Git.

Comment: if you have vs 2015 you can uninstall this...makes things like that easy...assuming you have permissions...https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power ...there's not a 2017 version

Comment: *I've tried to go for some Command Lines but no success.* -- You tried something. It didn't work. **What didn't work when you tried it?** Did you get a specific error message?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Yes, like I said in the beginning of the question I've checked the permissions I need to do those actions (there is a link to the manual)

Comment: @DanielMann My bad, those are the results of the commands that I've listed:
**tf lock command**
`TF400032: The operation could not be completed because the workspace WORKSPACE;NAME_EMPLOYEE is a local workspace.` 

**tf workspace command**
`No workspace in the cache matches NAME_EMPOYEE for server https://SERVERNAME`

**tf undo command**
`TF14061: The workspace WORKSPACE;NAME_EMPLOYEE does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which output you got when you run the commands, but there is another option to unlock someone else lock or delete his old workspace, it's a [TFS Sidekicks](https://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm) tool.

After you download and install the tool, you can search the locked files and unlock them (and undo pending changes), search the workspace and delete him.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not use this kind of program because it's not official. Our politics do not permit ... I really wanted to try it :(